# If I have large worksheet full of data, is it possible to just pull out country names using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

As the title implies, I have a large dataset. Column B contains a list of numbers. In each row, there is a number of cells containing an amalgamation of text. Some are twenty cells long, with random names and country names throughout. I want to write a script to pull out whatever country appears in each, and paste them into column A.

The pseudo, unworking script I have so far is:

```
Sub PullCountries()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

While i <= LastRow
Set Rng = Range("B" & i)

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Row(i:i), "United States") Then 'this doesn't work at the moment for triggering when these words appear 
"United States".Copy 'not sure how to be specific here
Rng.Offset(0, -1).paste special

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Row(i:i), "Canada") Then
"Canada".Copy 
Rng.Offset(0, -1).paste special

'My plan was to write a line for the countries that appear most common, then carry out the rest manually. 


Else: i + i = 1

End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Obviously, the line "United States".Copy doesn't work, and (Row(i:i)) is bringing up an error.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Will any row contain more than one country??

Comment: `If CBool(Application.CountIf(Rows(i), "United States")) Then`

Comment: Some may contain more than one. Once I get the phrasing right, I should able to control for that.

Comment: I'll have a suggestion for you in the morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the `FindAll` method. [This](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx) gives an overview.

```
Dim SearchRange As Range, FindWhat As Variant, FoundCells As Range, FoundCell As Range

FindWhat = Array("Country1","Country2","Country3",etc)
Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")

For s = LBound(FindWhat) to UBound(FindWhat)
    Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, FindWhat:=FindWhat(s), LookIn:=xlValues,LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not FoundCells Is Nothing Then
        For each FoundCell In FoundCells
            FoundCell.Offset(,-1).Value = FoundCell.Value
        Next
    End If
Next s
```

The code I wrote above will loop through the column B looking for each value/country name you provide in the array FindWhat. For each instance that it finds of a country it will paste the country into columnA on the same row. Let me know if you wanted to paste it at the first open/top of column A instead of on the same row each value was found and I'll adjust the code accordingly. It wasn't clear to me which of the two you wanted. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely seems like the right track. I was initially getting a function not found error for Find All, which I assume I could put in as a separate function in the form of, `Function FindAll(SearchRange As Range, _ Find....`

As outlined in the link. But now I am getting a type mismatch for FindWhat. Is there anything else I need to consider for defining a string as an Array like this?

Comment: My mistake, `FindWhat()` should be declared as a Variant like so `FindWhat() As Variant`. I've updated my code above and it runs through for me now.